# Workbook object persists after closing and workbook reopens on any subsequent excel action after the workbook has been closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook that acts as a Launchpad for other excel based tools allow the user to launch multiple instances of the same tool I am forcing the new tools to open in a new excel instance each time by setting a new application. The code then also passes some data from the launchpad into the tools as well.

Unfortunately for some users, currently only a handful from some 20-30 that have used the system, if they close the launchpad workbook it seems to persist in that instance of excel (It remains visible in the VBE project explorer). What's stranger is that whatever they now do in any workbook that remains opened in that instance of excel e.g.type into a cell and press return, the launchpad is re-opened. They have to completely shut down excel to stop the issue.

I release all the objects used in the routine that opens the tools so it can not be this, I am wondering if this is necessary given I am opening the workbooks and wanting to leave them open for the user?

### My Code:

```
Public Sub LaunchTool()
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WT1 As Workbook
Dim EA1 As New Application

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Define workbook aliases
Set WT1 = ActiveWorkbook
EA1.Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathString, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True,                 
ReadOnly:=True

Set WB1 = EA1.ActiveWorkbook
Set WS1 = WB1.Worksheets("Import")
WB1.Windows(1).Visible = True
EA1.Visible = True


'pass on some values
WB1.Sheets("Control").Range("Dev_Flag") =                     
WT1.Sheets("Param").Range("Dev_Flag")

Set WT1 = Nothing
Set WS1 = Nothing
Set WB1 = Nothing
Set EA1 = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is to suppress the *Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action* alert that sometimes pops up during the loading.

I have tried the following in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private WithEvents XL As Excel.Application

Private Sub XL_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
Set XL = Nothing
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.FullName
ThisWorkbook.Close False 
End Sub
```

But no luck!

For most users, everything works fine but some users as I described cannot successfully close down the launchpad and then unless they close excel completely or at least the instance that the launchpad was open in then any user action begins to trigger the launchpad to reopen.

Thanks.

Comment: Should be closing the workbook you're opening with `WB1.close()` and quitting the Excel Application with `EA1.quit()` before setting both to nothing. Also when making the definition I would use `Dim EA1 as Excel.Application` then later on when you're creating object in code `Set EA1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` After making this change let me know if error persists, if it does you're likely not correctly handling the application somewhere else in code, I know sometimes if you define a range on another sheet you opened it can leave a phantom trace in memory which is why it might notquit

Comment: @RileyCarney there's never any reason to use `CreateObject` to create a new instance of a class that's already known to the compiler. You're hitting the registry to locate a ProgID, find the library on disk, load the type from that library, create a new instance, and return it -- all for a type that's right there waiting to be used. `Set EA1 = New Excel.Application`, accomplishes the same thing, without the trip to the moon and back.

Comment: The point about `WB1.Close` and `EA1.Quit` is good though.

Comment: I know haha. I usually just define something as an object and then attempt to create the object so it can catch it if it fails as it's more generic and they wouldn't necessarily have the instance of the class always but with excel.application there's really no point if they're using vba in excel. It's just always something to keep in mind, especially since sometimes if you try to create a class that you need to check to add it to compile you can createobject often times but not do the direct class.

Comment: Hi Both, thank you for your responses. I have tested the `WT1.close, WB1.close, EA1.quit' it seems to half solve the issue as the workbook is no longer triggered but its still visible in VBE. That said the purpose is to open WB1 for use so this solution defeats it.

Comment: @RileyCarney Doesn't seem to solve the issue, what is the best way to identify if I am mishandling the application somewhere else. Also as per my first comment above (sorry I didn't realise I needed to @ users), .close and .quit stopped the strange re-opening but workbook was still visible in VBE. If I what I need is to leave the workbook open should I veen be setting the objects to nothing? Could this possibly be the problem?

Comment: If you wanted to leave it open then you shouldn't set it to nothing, usually it means the garbage collector will collect the application. However, sometimes in vba its weird and won't, that's why I said use close or quit. I'd recommend setting the workbook outside of the function as a global variable, that way after the function is ran you still are able to access it in other functions outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

After much deliberation, I realised that the issue was not being driven by the objects but rather that I had an `Application.OnKey` trigger that was being set but never released and this was causing the workbook to persist, releasing the OnKey trigger in the `WorkbookBeforeClose` routine has solved it nicely.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was:

```
WorkbookToClose.Close SaveChanges:=False
```